# How to return data in function passed to flatmap

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a file of data in the following schema:

```
+--------------------+-------------------+
|           full_text|                 id|
+--------------------+-------------------+
```

I want to change each record to pairs of (token, id). For example for record `Hi, how are you, 1010` I want it to transform to:

```
(hi, 1010)
(how, 1010)
(are, 1010)
(you, 1010)
```

So I did it using SparkSql in the following way:

```
data = spark.read.json("../input/Spark_tweets.json").select("full_text", "id")
data.rdd.map(lambda data : (data[0], data[1]))\
    .flatMap(lambda row: generateWordPlusId(row[0], row[1])).saveAsTextFile("out")
```

and the `generateWordPlusId` function does:

```
def generateWordPlusId(sentence, id):
    t = []
    for i in [word for word in sentence.lower().split()]:
        t.append((i, id))
    return tuple(t)
```

and it works as desired. My question is the function that we passed to a `flatMap` method, like `generateWordPlusId` in my case, what exactly should returns? I insert data into a 2-D array and at last convert it to the tuple to return. Is this typical approach and optimized or there is a better way to do that?